# Trouble redirecting to HTTPS with PHP

Tags: php

I just had an ssl installed for a site I am working on and I obviously need to get a few of the pages (checkout etc) redirected to https.

I am currently using this code:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || !$_SERVER['HTTPS']) {   
    $url = 'https://www.mysite.php';
    header("location: ". $url);
    exit();
}
```

Firefox is telling me that "the page is trying to redirect in a way that will never complete."

A var_dump of $_SERVER shows no ['HTTPS'] or similar when I am on the secure page. This is on a Network Solutions small unix package. Is it possible I need to be checking for a different server variable or perhaps I need to change some server settings?

Clearly the script is never finding HTTPS so it is trying to redirect without end.

Comment: I think `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` is Apache-specific. If they're using nginx or something else it may not show up at all.

Comment: Why not use rewrite engine? it works well.

Answer (score 0):

It becomes clearer if you use `OR`:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) OR !$_SERVER['HTTPS']) {
```

Chances are one of the conditions always evaluates to true, even when you already are in HTTPs mode.

You want `AND`:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) AND !$_SERVER['HTTPS']) {
```

Comment: or thanks to what's-his-name's-law, `if( ! (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'] OR !$_SERVER['HTTPS']) )` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I use this form of SSL Checking too. For me my code works. Here is what i do.

```
if(empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "on") {
    header("Location: https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
```

This works great and also redirects you to the previous url.

hope this helps.

Comment: If you want to check if the _SERVER exist, please do a print_r($_SERVER); on a page which you can access through Https. check then if the variable key HTTPS isset. or if you can find any key which could indicates that you are on https mode (maybe you got a location key where the current location including current scheme is stored) so in some cases you could do a preg_match with "/^https:\/\//" and check so if https is using.

Comment: print_r($_SERVER) shows no differences between when on HTTP and when on HTTPS page...and I scanned over it several times!

Comment: Than your Webserver do not set this flag if you are on https mode. Edit: Sorry pressed enter. so i created at my server a file which prints $_SERVER i have the follwing key which also indicates ssl: SSL_TLS_SNI also i have at my page included SERVER_SIGNATURE and there is a string like ...Port 443</address>  so maybe if you know that port XXX is only used for ssl you can preg match there

Comment: Yeah, the one thing I did notice was some changing port numbers, so that could be a possible solution that I will check. Will report back..

Comment: If you have access to the webserver config, (own server) you can also handle the _SERVER key manualy go to your http port 80 virtual host setting and within the virtualhost section write SetEnv USE_SSL 0 then go to your ssl virtual host and use the same config but for 0 use 1 so you can check against that $_SERVER['USE_SSL'] instead of HTTPS. in this case for my code change "on" to "1" or you can add on ssl virtual host the SSLOptions +StdEnvVars than the HTTPS key (and the SSL_TLS) should be available

Comment: uggg, see I don't think I have access to anything like that. I really dislike network solutions...can't get client to change.